# when i add new comment the delete button doesn't work till i reload the page?

Tags: php, ajax

## first page

## ajax and jquery code

```
 <script> 

    $(document).ready(function(){   

    $(".delete_buttom").click(function(){ 

    var x = $(this).attr('id');  

    click_delete(x); 

});  

 function click_delete(commentId){   

    $.post("ajax_comments3.php",  
{  
    task : "this is the task",  

    commentId : commentId  

 }).success(  

    function(data){  

       $('#comment_' + commentId).remove();  

 }).error(function(){  

     alert("404 not found");         

 });  

 }   

 </script>
```

======================================================================

## second page code

```
<?php  

if(isset($_POST['task']) && $_POST['task'] == "this is the task"){      

    $server_id = $_POST['ajax_id'];  

    $server_comment = $_POST['ajax_text'];  

    $user_name = $_POST['ajax_uname'];  

    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","comments") 

    $insert_query = "insert into comment (commet_text,user_id) 
                       values ('$server_comment','$server_id')";  

    $excute_insert = mysqli_query($connection,$insert_query) or die("insert query error");  

?>
```

## this the the li tage which will insert into ul tage (i have a ul tage in html code)

```
    <li class="li_style" id="comment_<?php echo mysqli_insert_id($connection) ?>">  

    <img src="profile.jpg" class="user_img_src" />  

    <h5 class="username"><?php echo $user_name ; ?></h5>  

    <div class="delete_buttom" id="comment_<?php echo mysqli_insert_id($connection) ?>">X</div>  

   <div class="user_comment"><?php echo $server_comment ; ?> </div>  

  </li>  

<?php   

    }

?>
```

when i type a new comment it inserted into database and appear in the web browser as well but the problem is that i have a delete button when i clicked on it right after typing comment it doesn't work i have to reload the page the the delete button works fine any solutions.

Comment: It doesnt look like the delete button has an id attached

Comment: David Jones , yes i don't dut an id for the new button so if i did that what's next

Comment: but your click event takes an ID from the element to pass into the AJAX function so any new delete buttons that are added need to have an ID. If you do that then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Correct. That is because theres no event on that new button.

Maybe like this:

```
var deleteButton = function() {
    $(".delete_buttom").off('click');
    $(".delete_buttom").on('click', function() {
        var x = $(this).attr('id');  
        click_delete(x); 
    });

}
```

Now, in your success (after you added the new entry):

```
 success(function(data) {
     // add your entry...
     deleteButton();
 });
```

Comment: Celoain, I don't understand why you but the click off then change it into on

Comment: We take it off so the event won't get applied multiple times to the same Link. Also, what exactly is not working? Prepare a fiddle with your implementation so we can debug.

Comment: i put the code that you suggested in above comment but its not working still the same